# How to get selected item from ComboBox on Ionic 2?

Tags: php, android, sql, ionic2

I'm trying to get the selected item from a comboBox on Ionic 2, but I don't know how to since I can't have php code on the html page where the comboBox is.

The ComboBox is populated from an array I retrieve from a database. Also, I'm looking to get the selected item so I can redirect to a different page with the information of that item.

Here's my code:

home.html

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="categorias">
    <ion-label>Seleccione Categoria</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming">
      <ion-option value="{{cates.idCategoria}}" *ngFor="let cates of cate">{{cates.nombreCAT}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Your varible `gaming` is storing the selected value

Answer (score 1):

You can view the selected item's id on

```
this.categorias
```

which will equal

```
SELECTED_cates.idCategoria
```

Also for setting the value of the ion-option just use brackets

```
<ion-option [value]="cates.idCategoria" ...etc ></ion-option>
```

if you use value="something" it will set value with the string "something" like

```
this.value = "something"
```

When you use [value]="something" with brackets it will set it like. You should read more about how angular2 binding works.

```
this.value = this.something
```

Finally if you want an action to take place immediately when selecting it use

```
(ionChange)="methodname()"
```

Comment: and how would I received the selected value on my new method to pass it down to a php?

Comment: Uhh I'm assuming that your typescript (javascript) is executed on the client side. While the php code is on the server side typically. So you can't just "pass it down" to a php. You'll need to call your server to serve a new page or url link. I suggest you read a tutorial of how to implement javascript and php.